# How to determine if SQLConnection belong to the current ambient transaction System.Transactions.Transaction.Current?

Tags: transactions, transactionscope, sqlconnection, dts

What I want know is if a given `SQLConnection` is *enlisted* with the current *ambient transaction* in a given time, I mean, putting something in the watch while debugging that allow me know if one connection is enlisted with the *current ambient transaction*. I'm debugging code that create several instances of `TransactionScope` class and the code not call neither `TransactionScope.Complete` or `TransactionScopeDispose` before new instances of `TransactionScope` are created. So if I could know if a given `SQLConnection` is enlisted in the current `ambient transaction` will be very useful.

BTW, the `TransactionScope` is not created using `using`statement, so is hard know reading the code what `SQLConnection` belong to what `TransactionScope` instance.

Answer (score 0):

The enlisted transaction is stored in the `SqlInternalConnection`'s [`EnlistedTransaction` field](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/ProviderBase/DbConnectionInternal.cs,763f60f2977c09fd). This field is set [here in the EnlistNonNull method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Data/R/397df28e279da73e.html). You can get access to that field with reflection.